# Is there a way to measure latency of multiple loads in parallel in x86 (using RDTSCP or RDTSC), without serialization?

Tags: performance, x86, memory-barriers, microbenchmark, transactional-memory

I am trying to measure the latency of multiple memory accesses that are executing in parallel in an out-of-order processor.

**The problem is that any attempt to measure the latency of a load serializes it with 
respect to other loads.**

Take for example a naively written code that measures the latency of two loads:

```
1. rdtscp
2. load-1
3. rdtscp

4. rdtscp 
5. load-2
6. rdtscp
```

In the above code, the ordering property of *rdtscp* in Intel's x86 serializes the execution of load-1 and load-2 as per my testing (i.e. load-2 is issued to the memory-system only after load-1 completes execution). As a result, the above code does not utilize the available memory bandwidth. Ideally, I would like to ensure the maximum throughput for the loads, while measuring the latency of each load independently.

**Is there a way to measure latency of load-1 and load-2, while allowing them to execute in parallel?**

Ideally, what I need is a form of rdtscp that is ordered with respect to the load whose latency is being measured, and not ordered explicitly with any other instruction. I was wondering if there is a way to obtain this either with *rdtscp* or *rdtsc*.

Comment: [Description of rdtsc](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/rdtscp) suggests that "rdtscp waits until all previous instructions have executed and all previous loads are globally visible". So it is not directly usable for my purpose.

Comment: [A previous Stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52158572/whats-up-with-the-half-fence-behavior-of-rdtscp#comment100016635_52158572) opined that rdtscp enforces full lfence like behaviour: any load instructions on either side of an rdtscp call do not get re-ordered aruond it. I have observed similar behaviour in my testing which prompted this question.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's any way to sample a time with an input-dependency on a specific register, or any other way to let loads complete out of order but still time each one individually.  Or even to just let them overlap.

---

There are perf events for `mem_trans_retired.load_latency_gt_32` and so on for powers of 2 from 4 to 512.  You could program counters and `rdpmc` for that.  But it wouldn't tell you which load triggered which event.

Given your overall goal, you could use those counters with `perf stat` or `perf record` to get an average for a whole loop case when (single-core) memory bandwidth is maxed out.

Note that they count latency from first dispatch (to a load port), not issue into the back-end.