# Calling cpuid before rdtsc to prevent out of order?

Tags: c, x86-64, cpuid, rdtsc

I am trying to call cpuid before my rdtsc function to prevent out of order. I initially used this rdtsc function to get 2 timestamps and often I get negative numbers, which is undesirable. This is the rdtsc function, how should I implement cpuid? Or is it called int the main function?

```
inline uint64_t rdtsc() {
    unsigned long a, d;
    asm volatile ("rdtsc":"=a" (a), "=d" (d));
    return a | ((uint16_t)d << 32);
}
```

Comment: Some information in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12065721/why-isnt-rdtsc-a-serializing-instruction). There are many others as well that deal with this issue.

Comment: Usually you want `lfence` as a barrier to OoO exec, not a slow CPUID.  See also [How to get the CPU cycle count in x86\_64 from C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13772567) for working code to run `rdtsc` which avoids truncating the high 32 bits to 16-bit.

Comment: See also [What's up with the "half fence" behavior of rdtscp?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52158572)  (And the list of duplicates linked at the top of the page.  Some of them show `_mm_lfence()`, or putting `lfence; rdtsc` into one asm template.)

Comment: Thank you very much. Can we describe lfence/mfence as a more focused way of serializing instructions as opposed to using cpuid? I noticed that it is slower to use cpuid, measurements take longer.

Answer (score 1):

The behavior of `(uint16_t) d << 32` is not defined by the C standard.

The left operand of `<<` is `(uint16_t) d`. After the cast, the integer promotions are performed, so the `uint16_t` value is converted to an `int`.<sup>1</sup> This is likely 32 bits in your C implementation. The C standard does not define the behavior of `<<` when the shift amount equals or exceeds with left operand width.

To fix this code, use `return a | (uint64_t) d << 32;`.

Most compilers warn about this. Pay attention to compiler warning messages. Preferably, elevate them to errors. (With GCC or Clang, use `-Werror`. With MSVC, use `/WX`.)

### Footnote

<sup>1</sup> This assumes `int` is wider than 16 bits. If `int` is only 16 bits, `(uint16_t) d << 32` is still undefined because 32 is wider than the left operand type, 16.